# connect to an already open headless browser for automation

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to connect to the browser with Selenium but it's giving an error on the line driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)  , saying:

Message: unknown error: cannot connect to microsoft edge at localhost:9222
from unknown error: unable to discover open pages:

```
import subprocess
import threading
import psutil
from selenium import webdriver
import time


def encerrar_processos_edge():
    for proc in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']):
        if 'msedge.exe' in proc.info['name']:
            try:
                process = psutil.Process(proc.info['pid'])
                process.terminate()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Erro ao encerrar processo: {e}")
                
encerrar_processos_edge()  



caminho_edge = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"  # Substitua pelo caminho correto
opcao_invisivel = "--headless"
opcao_debug = "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
             
def abrir_edge():
    subprocess.run([caminho_edge,opcao_invisivel, opcao_debug])



thread = threading.Thread(target=abrir_edge, daemon=True)
thread.start()



time.sleep(10)



def Ativar_Selenium():
     # Configuração do navegador Chrome
    options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()    
    # A mesma porta usada no navegador aberto
    options.debugger_address = 'localhost:9222'  
    # Iniciar o driver como variavel global
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)   
    # Execute o código JavaScript em um evento futuro
    driver.get('https://www.google.com/')


Ativar_Selenium()
```

This error only happens with headless turned on, when turned off it works normally, I wanted to be able to connect even with headless turned on, would there be a solution?